# Framelayout for TV UI with a listview and videoview, the listview item can't got focus with keyCode

Tags: android, android-layout

The layout file is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<VideoView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/soundcontroller"
    />
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/siderbar" >
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listviewmain" >

        </ListView>

        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listviewall" >

        </ListView>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/soundcontroller" >
    <include layout="@layout/activity_sound_controller"/>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

How can the ListView or other view? If the VideoView set a video url to play, all time it focus on the VideoView control bar and can't move to others... It's painful. Thanks.

Edit 1: I run getCurrentFocus(), it's alway focus on VideoView...

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution: to force focus to a specific view like sidebar, just call requestFocus().